# Django Lambda Function request times out after inactivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

Currently, I have a Django REST API Lambda function running in a VPC which accesses an Aurora Serverless cluster inside of the same VPC. The API is consumed by a React app. The API works as intended and I am able to connect, but sometimes the requests time out after about 30 seconds. This timeout only happens after the API has not been used for about a minute. After I refresh the page a few times which I assume warms up the Lambda, the requests go through and I am able to get data. After a bit of inactivity, the requests timeout again and I have to refresh. While refreshing works, it is definitely not what I want for my app and it is very tedious.

Here is the YAML file I used to create the VPC on Cloudformation:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  pubPrivateVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 172.31.0.0/16
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref AWS::StackName
  publicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
         - 0
         - Fn::GetAZs: ""
      CidrBlock: 172.31.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","public-subnet"]]
  privateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
         - 0
         - Fn::GetAZs: ""
      CidrBlock: 172.31.3.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","private-subnet-a"]]
  privateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
         - 1
         - Fn::GetAZs: ""
      CidrBlock: 172.31.2.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","private-subnet-b"]]
  internetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","gateway"]]
  gatewayToInternet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref internetGateway
  publicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
  publicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: gatewayToInternet
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref publicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref internetGateway
  publicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref publicSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref publicRouteTable
  natGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    DependsOn: natPublicIP
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt natPublicIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref publicSubnet1
  natPublicIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: pubPrivateVPC
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  privateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
  privateRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref privateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref natGateway
  privateSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref privateSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref privateRouteTable
  privateSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref privateSubnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref privateRouteTable
  s3Endpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: "*"
          Action:
            - "s3:*"
          Resource:
            - "*"
      RouteTableIds:
        - !Ref privateRouteTable
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
Outputs:
  pubPrivateVPCID:
    Description: VPC ID
    Value: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
    Export:
      Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","vpc"]]
  publicSubnet1ID:
    Description: Public Subnet A ID
    Value: !Ref publicSubnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","public-subnet-a"]]
  privateSubnet1ID:
    Description: Private Subnet A ID
    Value: !Ref privateSubnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","private-subnet-a"]]
  privateSubnet2ID:
    Description: Private Subnet B ID
    Value: !Ref privateSubnet2
    Export:
      Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","private-subnet-b"]]
  privateVPCSecurityGroup:
    Description: Default security for Lambda VPC
    Value: !GetAtt pubPrivateVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","vpc-sg"]]
```

When I use try to make fetch calls with my React frontend, I get this response:

```
status: 504
via: 1.1 [cloudfront url].cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amzn-errortype: InternalServerErrorException
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

I assume this is a problem with cold starting the Lambda function as it times out after 30 seconds which is the maximum request time of the function. I have a Cloudwatch event to keep the function warm every minute but it has not helped. I have also raised the memory of the Lamdba function to 1408 mb but that has not helped either. Any help speeding up the connection or helping with cold starts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcin yes, the Lambda is on the publicSubnet1, privateSubnet1, and privateSubnet2. The Aurora Cluster is on both private subnets. The Lambda has been able to access data successfully but it may be a problem starting the connection to the cluster

Comment: Interesting.  According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html), the lambda will reclaim the network interface  "If your functions are not active for **a long period of time**". In [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/) it suggests that this long time is measured in  "weeks". So I suspect that something else is causing the 30 seconds timeouts.

Comment: What about the Aurora serverless startup times and settings? It can also be long as reported [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/09/amazon-aurora-serverless-the-sleeping-beauty/) for instance.

Comment: @Marcin I disabled pausing of compute capacity but the problem still persists.

Comment: Could you clarify your architecture? I see that error quoted is from `cloudfront`? So you have some Django app running somewhere (ec2 instance in the vpc?), which connects to CloudFront, which then goes to API Gateway, which calls Lambda set for vpc access, which then in turn accesses the Aurora in the same vpc?

Comment: @Marcin I use [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa), a Python serverless framework to handle my Lambda updates. While I am not very experienced with AWS, from what I know, API Gateway will handle the request and call the Lambda for VPC access. From there, the Lambda accesses the Aurora cluster inside of the VPC. I am not sure why I am getting a cloudfront error as I do not have any cloudfront distributions. I used cloudformation for creating the resources I needed but as far as I know, there is no resource I created associated with a cloudfront distribution.

Comment: Difficult to pinpoint the issue. I would try to analyze your setup step by step. For example, what happens when you directly call the lambda using `aws lambda invoke` CLI? Do you also observe the same problem? Then what happens when you `curl` the api gateway directly? P.S. If you API gateway is set in an Edge mode, then it uses cloudfront in the backend. So this may explain why you see cloudfront  error.

Comment: *An HTTP 504 status code (Gateway Timeout) indicates that when CloudFront forwarded a request to the origin (because the requested object wasn't in the edge cache), one of the following happened: The origin returned an HTTP 504 status code to CloudFront. The origin didn't respond before the request expired.* - Could be a red-herring but are you using Lambda on the Edge? How else is it going to edge locations, cloudfront? Is that the default for Zappa - does a SAM file come with the zip?

Comment: Do you need public subnets and a NAT gateway? Do you need to access anything over internet?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but in my case, it was caused by inactive Aurora being paused